# Interpreting basic output from Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I had a couple questions about the output from a simple run of VW. I have read around the internet and the wiki sites but am still unsure about a couple of basic things.

I ran the following on the boston housing data:

```
vw -d housing.vm --progress 1
```

where the housing.vm file is set up as (partially):

[image]

and output is (partially):

[image]

**Question 1:**

1) Is it correct to think about the average loss column as the following steps:

a) predict zero, so the first average loss is the squared error of the first example (with the prediction as zero)

b) build a model on example 1 and predict example 2. Average the now 2 squared losses

c) build a model on example 1-2 and predict example 3. Average the now 3 squared losses

d) ...

Do this until you hit the end of the data (assuming a single pass)

2) What is the current features columns? It appears to be the number of non-zero features + an intercept. What is shown in the example, suggests that a feature is not counted if it is zero - is that true? For instance, the second record has a value of zero for 'ZN'. Does VW really look at that numeric feature as missing??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statements are basically correct. By default, VW does online learning, so in step c it takes the current model (weights) and updates it with the current example (rather than learning from all the previous examples again).

As you supposed, the current *features column* is the number of (non-zero) features for the current example. The intercept feature is included automatically, unless you specify `--noconstant`.

There is no difference between a missing feature and a feature with zero value. Both means that you won't update the corresponding weight.

Comment: I am happy to hear I understand, thank you! I am curious about these though - is what I described for the average loss the same as is described as 'progressive validation' by Dr. Langford? The idea of picking a test set of size 's' and such he describes did not seem as simple as what I laid out above.

Comment: The fact of the missing feature being the same as a zero value makes sense once I recalled the sgd update rule.

Comment: If you do one pass (or with `--holdout_off`), VW uses (and reports) progressive validation. This means: 1. you see a new example and its correct label, 2. you compute a loss for this example based on the model learned so far (and with `--progress 1` you immediately report it as 'since last'), 3. you learn from the example, i.e. you update the model based on the current example.