# Vowpal Wabbit Continuing Training

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Continuing with some experimentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838461/interpreting-basic-output-from-vowpal-wabbit/25842936#25842936) I was interested is seeing how to continuing training a VW model.

I first ran this and saved the model.

```
vw -d housing.vm --loss_function squared -f housing2.mod --invert_hash readable.housing2.mod
```

Examining the readable model:

```
Version 7.7.0
Min label:0.000000
Max label:50.000000
bits:18
0 pairs: 
0 triples: 
rank:0
lda:0
0 ngram: 
0 skip: 
options:
:0
 ^AGE:104042:0.020412
 ^B:158346:0.007608
 ^CHAS:102153:1.014402
 ^CRIM:141890:0.016158
 ^DIS:182658:0.278865
 ^INDUS:125597:0.062041
 ^LSTAT:170288:0.028373
 ^NOX:165794:2.872270
 ^PTRATIO:223085:0.108966
 ^RAD:232476:0.074916
 ^RM:2580:0.330865
 ^TAX:108300:0.002732
 ^ZN:54950:0.020350
Constant:116060:2.728616
```

If I then continue to train the model using two more examples (in housing_2.vm), which note, has zero values for ZN and CHAS:

```
27.50 |  CRIM:0.14866 ZN:0.00 INDUS:8.560 CHAS:0 NOX:0.5200 RM:6.7270 AGE:79.90 DIS:2.7778 RAD:5 TAX:384.0 PTRATIO:20.90 B:394.76 LSTAT:9.42
26.50 |  CRIM:0.11432 ZN:0.00 INDUS:8.560 CHAS:0 NOX:0.5200 RM:6.7810 AGE:71.30 DIS:2.8561 RAD:5 TAX:384.0 PTRATIO:20.90 B:395.58 LSTAT:7.67
```

If the model saved is loaded and training continues, the coefficients appear to be lost from these zero valued features. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

```
vw -d housing_2.vm --loss_function squared -i housing2.mod --invert_hash readable.housing3.mod
```

output from readable.housing3.mod:

```
Version 7.7.0
Min label:0.000000
Max label:50.000000
bits:18
0 pairs: 
0 triples: 
rank:0
lda:0
0 ngram: 
0 skip: 
options:
:0
 ^AGE:104042:0.023086
 ^B:158346:0.008148
 ^CRIM:141890:1.400201
 ^DIS:182658:0.348675
 ^INDUS:125597:0.087712
 ^LSTAT:170288:0.050539
 ^NOX:165794:3.294814
 ^PTRATIO:223085:0.119479
 ^RAD:232476:0.118868
 ^RM:2580:0.360698
 ^TAX:108300:0.003304
Constant:116060:2.948345
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue *learning* from saved state in a smooth fashion you must use the `--save_resume` option.

There are 3 fundamentally different types of "state" that can be saved into a `vw` "model" file:

1. The weight vector (regressor) obviously. That's the model itself.
2. invariant parameters like the version of `vw` (to ensure binary compatibility which is not always preserved between versions), number of bits in the vector (`-b`), and type of model
3. state which dynamically changes during learning. This subset includes parameters like learning and decay rates which gradually change during learning with each example, the example numbers themselves, etc.

Only `--save_resume` saves the last group.

--save_resume is not the default because it has an overhead and in most use-cases it isn't needed.  e.g. if you save a model once in order to do many predictions and no learning (`-t`), there's no need in saving the 3rd subset of state.

So, I believe in your particular case, you want to use `--save_resume`.

The possibility of a bug always exists, especially since `vw` supports so many options (about 100 at last count) which are often interdependent. Some option combinations make sense, other don't. Doing a sanity check for roughly 2^100 possible option combinations is a bit unrealistic.  If you find a bug, please open an issue on github. In this case, please make sure to use a complete example (full data & command line) so your problem can be reproduced.

***Update 2014-09-20 (after an issue was opened on github, thanks!):***
The reason for 0 valued features "disappearing" (not really from the model, but only from the `--invert_hash` output) is that 1) `--invert_hash` was never designed for multiple passes, because keeping the original feature names in a hash-table, incurs a large performance overhead 2) The missing features are those with a zero value, which are discarded.  The model itself should still have any feature with any *prior* pass non-zero weight in it. Fixing this inconsistency is too complex and costly for implementation reasons, and would go against the overriding motivation of making `vw` fast, especially for the most useful/common use-cases.  Anyway, thanks for the report, I too learned something new from it.

Comment: I was not aware of that flag (what it did). Thanks very much!

Comment: I do think there are issues - perhaps only superficially and if I can figure out how to open an issue and add the data, I will submit.